# how to format string output using % in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string-formatting

I want to format the output of a string in ruby. I can do it using % but I cannot figure it out.

Instead of `201107070928` I want to output `2011\07\070928`

```
puts "%.4s\\%.2s\\%s" % "201107070928"
```

gives me an error:`%': too few arguments (ArgumentError)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to put this in an answer rather than a comment just because I'm more impressed with the possibility.  Using [String#unpack](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112), we can handle a 4 digit / 2 digit / **anything** with:

```
"201107070928345345345".unpack("a4a2a*").join('/')
 => "2011/07/070928345345345"
```

Comment: I am very happy with unpack too :-)

Answer (score 10):

That's not how you use it for formatting a date. The way to use `%` formatting is:

```
puts "%.4s\\%.2s\\%s" % ["1","2","3"]
```

So, you need multiple parameters - one for each of the format specifiers.

If you need to print & format a date from a string-date, first convert the string to a date/time object and then use `strftime`:

Presuming the input is date and a time:

```
Time.parse("201107070928").strftime("%Y\\%m\\%d%H%M").
```

Comment: So, is there any way to say: take first 4 chars from a string then add \\ then take 2 chars from the same string then add \\ and then the rest of the string?

Comment: `s = "201107070928"; puts "%s\\%s\\%s" % [ s[0...4], s[4...6], s[6..-1] ]` => `2011\07\070928`

Comment: Presuming the input is date and a time: `Time.parse("201107070928").strftime("%Y\\%m\\%d%H%M")`.

Comment: If you know the string is always that format, look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112  ...  "201107070928".unpack("a4a2a6").join('/')

Comment: Alternatively, use a Regexp to split the string into the parts you want, and then do whatever you want with the MatchData: `puts "%s\\%s\\%s" % "201107070928".match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d*)/).to_a[1..-1]`

Comment: The unpack could look like this also: `201107070928".unpack("A4A2A6").join("\\")`

Comment: I would complement the answer by @PaulAnnesley with a join : `"201107070928".match(/^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]*)$/).to_a[1..-1].join("/")`